# Помогите понять что именно обозначает interface BaseStream<T , S extends BaseStream<T , S>>

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

```
interface BaseStream<T , S extends BaseStream<T , S>>
```

Увидел в Java 8 вот такую конструкцию и мозг зашел за разум, как понять данный интерфейс? Как его правильно имплементировать? Когда следует при разработке вводить такие интерфейсы ?

Comment: Это интерфейс в котором используются два дженерика ([Generics](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial)). `S` должен быть наследником от класса `BaseStream`.

Comment: Этот интерфейс очень похож для реализации паттерна программирования "декоратор" (посмотрите код на вики), с применением дженериков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public interface BaseStream<T , S extends BaseStream<T , S>> {

        abstract void doSomething(T t, S s);

    }
```

одна реализация

```
public class BaseStreamImpl<S, I> implements BaseStream {

    public BaseStreamImpl(S s, BaseStream i ) {
    }


    @Override
    public void doSomething(Object o, BaseStream baseStream) {

        System.out.println(o);
        baseStream.doSomething("doSomething in BaseStreamImpl by " + baseStream.getClass().getName(), this);
    }
}
```

наследник

```
public class BaseStreamImplExtend<I ,S> extends BaseStreamImpl {
    public BaseStreamImplExtend(I i) {

        super(i, null );
        System.out.println("This is BaseStreamImplExtend class2");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(Object o, BaseStream baseStream) {

        System.out.println(o);
        baseStream.doSomething("doSomething in BaseStreamImplExtend by " + baseStream.getClass().getName(), this);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseStreamImplExtend<Integer, String> baseStreamImplExtendInteger = new BaseStreamImplExtend(1); // благодаря дженерику ты говоришь какого типа будут аргументы конструктора. 
    BaseStreamImplExtend<String, String> baseStreamImplExtendString   = new BaseStreamImplExtend("String value"); // другой наследник принимает совершенно другое значение. если тут передать Integer, то компилятор сразу будет ругаться, а не при выполнении программы 


    BaseStreamImpl bsI = new BaseStreamImpl("sd", baseStreamImplExtendInteger);

    BaseStreamImpl<String, Integer> bsImplSI = new BaseStreamImpl<>("BaseStreamImpl String value", baseStreamImplExtendInteger); // от того, что ты хочешь сделать зависит какой наследник передать для выполнения определенных задач 

    bsI.doSomething("1234", baseStreamImplExtendInteger);

}
```

результат

```
This is BaseStreamImpl class 1
This is BaseStreamImplExtend class 1
This is BaseStreamImpl class String value
This is BaseStreamImplExtend class String value
This is BaseStreamImpl class sd
This is BaseStreamImpl class BaseStreamImpl String value
1234
doSomething in BaseStreamImpl by BaseStreamImplExtend
doSomething in BaseStreamImplExtend by BaseStreamImpl
doSomething in BaseStreamImpl by BaseStreamImplExtend
doSomething in BaseStreamImplExtend by BaseStreamImpl
doSomething in BaseStreamImpl by BaseStreamImplExtend
```

очень часто такого рода интерфесы используются при создании своего стрима или фильтра.

Все зависит от поставленных задач.

Answer (score 4):

Подобная конструкция нужна для реализации "порождающих" паттернов при сохранении инкапсуляции.
Например, у интерфейса *BaseStream* есть метод

```
S   parallel()
```

Который вернёт "параллельный" стрим, эквивалентный вашему.

Предположим что у вас есть стрим *MyStream* для объектов типа *MyObject*.

```
class MyStream implements BaseStream<MyObject, MyStream >
```

А так же есть стрим, умеющий работать со множеством потоков -

```
class MyParallelStream extends MyStream {
    public MyParallelStream(MyStream parent) {
      //Инициализация параллельного стрима данными
    }
}
```

В таком случае в MyStream  вы сможете реализовать метод

```
public MyStream parallel() {
    return new MyParallelStream(this);
}
```

А снаружи это будет выглядеть как

```
MyStream oldStream = new MyStream();//конструктор как пример, на самом деле - некоторая инициализация.
MyStream newParallel = oldStream.parallel();
```

И вы уже работаете с быстрым параллельным вариантом даже не задумываясь что у вас что-то изменилось в классах.

Ещё одно преимущество такого подхода - если вы обнаружите, что реализация MyParallelStream содержит ошибки, которые очень сложно и долго исправить, вы можете выпустить быстрый фикс, исправив метод

```
public MyStream parallel() {
        return this;
}
```

Теперь метод возвращает ваш старый проверенный стрим, который хоть и не будет обрабатывать элементы многопоточно, но будет хотя бы корректно работать (хоть и медленней, чем ожидалось).